# How to get the command-line script of the running python program?

Tags: python, command-line

### Context

For example, there is a python file named `helloworld.py`, and I am using `python helloworld.py --arg1 --arg2` to run this python file.

### Question

What should I write in the python file `helloworld.py` to obtain its running command-line script, i.e., `python helloworld.py --arg1 --arg2`?

Comment: Laziest way `import sys; print(sys.executable, *sys.argv)`, but the args that have whitespaces will not be quoted properly on output but otherwise will be represented properly internally as a complete entry inside its element in `sys.argv`.

Comment: This is actually pretty difficult to do reliably.  What is your OS/platform?

Comment: It seems like @metatoaster solved my problem, thank you! One more thing, what if I add other environment variables like `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1`? Is that possible to print this?

Comment: @wim, I am using Linux.

Comment: @DylanWang On Linux reading `/proc/self/cmdline` will be closer to the original cmdline than `sys.argv`. It's still not perfect though, since the shell has already processed the cmdline to some extent (env vars, escaping, etc)

Comment: @metatoaster In general `sys.argv` can be missing some important parts (try example with `python3 -S helloworld.py`, the `-S` will not be there).

Answer (score 0):

2 options: `sys.argv` and `argparse`

`sys.argv`:

- Simpler, provides the command line arguments as a list of strings. So running

`python helloworld.py --arg1 --arg2`

will mean that `sys.argv` contains

`['helloworld.py', '--arg1', '--arg2']`

`argparse`:

- More feature rich. Unquestionably my recommendation for anything more than a singular argument.
- Supports positional and keyword arguments.
- Arguments mat have values and may be limited to presets.
- help is automatically generated
- Example:

```
## helloworld.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# Positional argument
parser.add_argument(
    "operator",
    help="Operator to use",
    choices=("add","subtract")
)
# Optional argument with value
parser.add_argument(
    "-i",
    "--integer",
    help="An integer",
    default=0
)
# Optional argument, True if present, otherwise False
parser.add_argument(
    "-sq",
    "--square-everything",
    action="store_true",
    help="Whether all numbers will get squared"
)
args = parser.parse_args() 
argument_dict = dict(args) # parse_args returns a namespace object
print(argument_dict)
```

```
python helloworld.py add -i 4 -sq
{"operator":"add", "integer":4, "square-everything": True}
```

Comment: The question asks how to get the original command line that was entered. I don't see what argparse has to do with anything here.

Comment: Like what @wim said, I am not asking for printing arguments, in your case, I need the program to print `python helloworld.py add -i 4 -sq`